# Pagination not working properly in angular

Tags: angular

I have a table where i applied pagination using ngx-pagination. The list in the table has edit and delete icon also. When i edit one of the list data on 2nd page and submit it, it redirects to 1st page. I want that when any edit is done from page other than 1 then after saving edits it remains on that page only. How can i achieve this???

*component.html*

```
       <table class="table tabs">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S. No.</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr
          *ngFor="
            let con of getAnaInfo
              | filter: searchText
              | paginate
                : {
                    itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,
                    currentPage: currentPage,
                    totalItems: totalItems
                  };
            let i = index
          "
        >
          <td>{{ (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage + i + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ con.Status }}</td>
          <td>{{ con.Rules.RuleName }}</td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-pencil" (click)="edit(con.Id, 
   currentPage)"></i></td>
         
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

*component.ts*

```
       edit(id, currentPage) {    
   this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/details/edit-page/" + id]);
    }
```

When "edit" function is triggered from page2 or more it is redirected to another page "editPageComponent.html" and when i submit, it throws back to 1st page.

*editPageComponent.ts*

```
 saveEdit(){      
  this.service
    .info(id,Info)
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        if (data.status == "success") {
          this.toastrService.success(data.message);             
          this.router.navigate([
            "/dashboard/details/list-data",
          ],
         );
        } else {
          this.toastrService.error(data.message);
        }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep the same `currentPage` value when trigger `edit()`.

Comment: in `edit()`, just don't change the value of `currentPage`. What i meant was that, let's say your table has 5 pages, and `currentPage` value is 2, then it will be in page 2 etc.
 
So in order to not return to page 1 as you said, you must keep the value of `currentPage` the same.

Comment: or you can show me your `edit()` function.

Comment: oh sorry edit and saveEdit are same function. I have made changes in above code also

Comment: can you please remove the `this.router.navigate()` part?

Comment: i have made some changes in code. Please check

Comment: Eh.. there is no point for me to check it, it's you. I mean you have to try to see if it works when you change your code. I cannot decide if your code is working as YOU expected or not.

Comment: And as i told you, just try to remove the `router.navigate()` part, and then re-run to see if it works.